# Discord.py Sql Создание игрового бота, ошибка

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sql, discord.py

Как мне создать переменную, что бы оно брало значение из бд? При комманде click, От значения upgrade, должно прибовлятся стока к балансу
Если сделать место upgrade, 10 то прибовляет по 10,мне нужно от upgrade значения брать

```
async def on_ready():
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT,
    id INT,
    cash BIGINT,
    rep INT,
    lvl INT,
    upgrade INT
  )""")

  for guild in client.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
      if cursor.execute(F"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1 , 10)")
        connection.commit()
      else:
        pass

  connection.commit()
  print('Бот присоеденился') 




@client.command()
async def click(ctx,member: discord.Member = None ):
  global upgrade
  cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + {} WHERE id = {}".format(upgrade, ctx.author.id))
  connection.commit()
  await ctx.send('+ ' + upgrade + ' cash') 
Моя коммандв click не работает. Ошибка :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\UsersНикитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\UsersНикитос\Desktop\discordbot.py", line 63, in click
    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + {} WHERE id = {}".format(upgrade, ctx.author.id))
NameError: name 'upgrade' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: что мне записать? Если я напишу например upgrade = 0,он и будет прибовлять 0,а  мне надо брать значение из бд

Comment: А, теперь понял. Ну так и берите из базы, переменная не нужна тогда. Написал ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если я всё правильно понял:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + upgrade WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))
```

А в самом питоне тогда глобальная переменная `global upgrade` вам не нужна.